# get references table name and table column

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I want to create query that result like this :

> column_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name

but I got a problem when build the referenced_table_name and referenced_column_name

this is my query

```
SELECT cols.column_name, cons.constraint_name, cons.constraint_type
FROM all_constraints cons,  all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'
AND cons.owner = 'HR'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
```

it just show column_name, constraint_name, and constraint_type. How do I show the rest?? Thank's for any help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select cols1.column_name
, r1.constraint_name
, r1.constraint_type 
, cols2.table_name
, cols2.column_name
from all_constraints r1
,    all_cons_columns cols1
,    all_cons_columns cols2
WHERE r1.constraint_name = cols1.constraint_name
AND   r1.owner = cols1.owner
and   r1.r_owner = cols2.owner(+)
and   r1.r_constraint_name = cols2.constraint_name(+)
AND cols1.table_name = 'EMPLOYEES' 
AND r1.owner = 'HR' 
/
```